# Regular expression to allow the format as YYMMDD

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox called period which should allow the user only to enter the string as YYMMDD format. YY can be numbers from 0-99, MM from 1-12 and DD from 01-04.

I want to use regular expression to get this done. Please help me with the expression to achieve this.

Comment: This is the first time that I am using the regular expressions and tried the below exp   if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtdate.Text, @"^[0-9][0-9][0-1][1-2][0-1][0-4]) Not sure if this is correct

Comment: I dont see anything wrong at first glance, what happens when you put an incorrect date in, like: "19890424"

Comment: You can test your regular expression here: http://regexlib.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `"^[0-9][0-9][0-1][1-2][0][1-4]$"` the error in your expression is that it will accept: 991214 which is incorrect.

Comment: The above expression is failing for the value 110403 but it passes 991204. Any idea?

Comment: You are correct, here is the resolution: ^[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|[1][1-2])[0][1-4]$

Answer (score 0):

`\d\d(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-4])`

- matches `110701`
- does not match `110705`

Comment: if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtdate.Text, "^dd(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-4])$")) always returns true